# Can one use Apple's Bootcamp drivers on a Parallels VM?

Tags: bootcamp, parallels-desktop

So this just occurred to me: What if I installed Windows as a Parallels VM and used bootcamps drivers instead of the parallels drivers, would this work?

Something tells me it won't, and that this is a really stupid question, in part because the VM is not actually your machine, but then again, it's a VM working ON the actual machine... no?

Comment: Why not download the Parallels drivers for Windows? Windows will probably refuse to install the bootcamp drivers as the hardware doesn't match up.

Answer (score 1):

This is unlikely to work, though I haven't tried it. If I may esplain...

The bootcamp drivers are for windows running on a specific number of Apple Macintosh computer models. In other words the drivers are for **specific** computers.

The Parallels VM is an emulated PC that may or may not have any compatibility with the Apple hardware.

It's kind of like going to the Dell drivers download site, downloading drivers for an (lets say...) Optiplex 9020 and than hoping those drivers will work on the new HP you just brought.